# Using reflection with derived objects

Tags: c#, reflection, nested, propertyinfo, derived-types

I am new to C# and need to perform a certain task using Reflection.

The thing is like this: I have a class called Derived which derives form a class called Base. Within the Base class I have another public class, which is a property called Prop class. Within the Prop class , there is a public property of type String called propString. Both Derived and Base class are under the same namespace. I depicted the situation below:

```
namespace mynamespace

public class Base {

    public Prop prop { get ; set;}


}

namespace mynamespace

public class Derived : Base {

    // some other properties of the derived class , not so relevant....
}


public class Prop {

     public String propString {get; set;}
}
```

I need to write two functions:

The first one receives a string of the "full path" of a property within a class and needs to extract the type of that property (In my case the string will be "Prop.propString" and the outcome of this method needs to be A PropertyInfo object with that property).

The second one gets an instance of an object and needs to perform a manipulation on the propString property (in my case the object that the function will get is A Derived object). 
I understood that it can be implemented in "more or less" that manner , yet it does not work well at the moment.

```
public void SecondFunc(Base obj) 
{
         PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
         object obj = new object();
         string value = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);

         string afterRemovalValue = myManipulationStringFunc(value);

         propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, afterRemovalValue, null);

}
```

Please your advises on how to implement these two functions, and off course any further insights you have will be highly appreciated.

Thanks allot in advance,

Guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish and if it is the best way to do it. But I have changed the code so it works. I have not made it as dynamic as it can be...

```
public class Base
{
    public Prop prop { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{

    // some other properties of the derived class , not so relevant....
}

public class Prop
{

    public String propString { get; set; }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public void SecondFunc(object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        var allClassProperties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in allClassProperties)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Prop))
            {
                var pVal = (Prop)propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
                if(pVal == null)
                {
                    //creating a new instance as the instance is not created in the ctor by default
                    pVal = new Prop();
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, pVal, null);
                }
                this.SecondFunc(pVal);
            }
            else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                string value = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
                string afterRemovalValue = myManipulationStringFunc(value);

                propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, afterRemovalValue, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private string myManipulationStringFunc(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            value = "Value was NULL";
        return value;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps...